# Objective C. NSMutable Dictionary adding value to existing key

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Is there any way to add a value to an existing key on a `NSMutableDictionary`?

Here is snippet of my code

```
 NSMutableArray *mainFeedList = [NSMutableArray array];
  [mainFeedList addObjectsFromArray:feedList];

  for(int i = 0; i < mainFeedList.count; i++){

    NSMutableArray *allFeed = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSString *categoryId = [mainFeedList[i] valueForKey: @"categoryId"];

    [allFeed addObject:mainFeedList[i]];

    if(allFeed != nil && allFeed.count > 0) {

      [feedContent setObject:allFeed
                      forKey:[combinedCategories[(int)[categoryId integerValue]] valueForKey: @"name"]];
    }
```

Sample scenario:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mDict = @{@"key1":@"value1",@"key2": @"value2"};
```

I know that

```
[mDict setObject:mArray forKey:@"key1"];
```

will set an object to `key1` but what I need is

add another object to `key1` without replacing existing object (i need it both)

Comment: Cannot be done. Dictionaries must have unique keys. If there are duplicates, you wont be able to fetch using a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A structure of any `NSDictionary` is "one key to one object". If you would like to build a structure which maps one key multiple objects, you need an `NSDictionary` that maps keys to collections, such as `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mDict = @{
    @"key1": [@[ @"value1" ] mutableCopy]
,   @"key2": [@[ @"value2" ] mutableCopy]
};
```

Now you can add values to keys without replacing the existing ones:

```
[mDict[@"key1"] addObject:@"value3"];
```

Comment: Should i check if the key is existing then if existed add an object to that key

Comment: will this code  [mDict[@"key1"] addObject:@"value3"]; add an object to key or it will just replace the current value

Comment: @SkyWalker Absolutely! This is just a quick illustration using the code from your question. `addObject` will add a second object for the same key, so you would end up with this structure: `@"key1": @[ @"value1", @"value3" ]`

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *dict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  
  if([dict valueForKey:@"name"] != nil) {
    [dict setValue:@"value" forKey:@"name"];
  }
  else {
  [dict[@"name"] addObject:@"value3"];
  }

Comment: @SkyWalker That's not going to work, because the object you add needs to be a mutable array, i.e. adding the first object needs to look like this: ` [dict setValue:[@[@"value"] mutableCopy] forKey:@"name"];`

Answer (score 0):

`NSDictionary` only allows a **single object corresponding to a single key**. If you would like to add **multiple objects corresponding to a single key**, if you have string type of object then you can use separators also to combine strings like:

`[mDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", [mDict objectforKey:@"key1"], @"value2"] forKey:@"key1"];`

Otherwise, you have to take collections, which you have already defined in your question.

Answer (score 0):

add another object to key1 without replacing existing object...

why not set an dict to key1?

before:

`[dict setObject:@"a" forKey:@"key1"];`

U wanna:

add @"b" to "key1", in dict;

why not like:

`[dict setObject:@{@"a":@"subKey1", @"b":@"subKey2"} forKey:@"key1"];`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest storing an array as a key in your dictionary like I do below :

```
// Setting the value for "key1" to an array holding your first value
NSMutableDictionary *mDict = @{@"key1":@["value1"],@"key2": @"value2"};
```

Now when I want to add a new value I would do this:

```
// Create temp array
NSMutableArray *temp = mDict[@"key1"];

// Add new object
[temp addObject:@"value3"];

// Convert temp NSMutableArray to an NSArray so you can store it in your dict
NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:temp];

// Replace old array stored in dict with new array
mDict[@"key1"] = newArray;
```

Furthermore, if you are not sure if an array is already stored for that key you can run a check and populate with an empty dictionary like below:

```
if (mDict[@"key1"] == nil) {
    mDict[@"key1"] = @[];
}
```